# Bootstrap Nav pills not working as spected using flexbox justify-content:space-between property

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am trying to use Bootstrap' nav-pills components with flexbox's  `justify-content:space-between`:
here is what I get as result:

[image]

while i expected this:

[image]

Here is the code: http://jsbin.com/qihekuteze

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing. For me, all the pills are pushed to the far left with like 2px of margin between them. Safari 8.0.4

Comment: Well I just test it on Chrome 41 and IE 11 but I have the same result... that's weird... :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because of Bootstrap's clearfix. There are `::before` and `::after` psuedo elements being added that are also counting as children of the flexbox.

If you add:

```
.nav::before,
.nav::after {
  display: none;
}
```

And make sure it's still `justify-content: space-between;`, then it will fix it.

New bin: http://jsbin.com/zipigociqi/1/

Comment: just beat me to it :)

Answer (score 3):

So after a fair amount of fiddling the issue is `content: " "` that bootstrap applies to `:before` and `:after` styles to the nav classes. So your css should be:

```
.nav::after, 
.nav::before {
    display: none;
}
```